What about Vika–Tech 52 and all the other clones of Jack and Vika?
In Oblivion (2013), the only time we ever see Vika–Tech 52 is when Jack–Tech 49 visits Jack–Tech 52's aerial base. The movie ends with Jack–Tech 52 having arrived at the lakeside cabin Jack–Tech 49 built, obviously having left his (Jack–Tech 52) aerial base for good. So how does it all conclude for Vika–Tech 52? And what happens to all the other clones of Jack and Vika once the Tet is destroyed? Is there any answer anywhere in the franchise or in the interviews?
"Is there any 'word-of-god' information on what happens after the events of the movie"

The story ended. Not much more than to say other they fend for themselves or die waiting in vain.

Voting to close as opinion-based as there's no way we can possibly know what happens to a movie's characters after the movie ends.

@F1Krazy - You mean aside from interviews with the cast and crew, sequels, tweets, deleted scenes, concept art, tie-in merchandise, novelisations, comic-books and spin-offs?

@F1Krazy - There was also a graphic novel; https://www.icgmagazine.com/web/exposure-joseph-kosinski/ and at least four different drafts of the script; https://imsdb.com/scripts/Oblivion.html

@F1Krazy - The director was talking about a sequel (possibly a prequel) at one point; https://www.hindustantimes.com/hollywood/oblivion-2-to-be-a-prequel/story-GCzZsOMbY5ghTMusSxv0IO.html

@Valorum – Thx so much! I did have in mind the possiblity of an answer being somewhere in the franchise besides the movie (I know about the graphic novel, and I admit I should've just got & read it) or in the interviews, and I thought it's possible someone on the site knows the answer from those elements.

@F1Krazy – I admit I should've mentioned what I told Valorum, in the post. I was aware this is no place for opinion-based posts, and If I yet broke the rules through lack of clarity, I'm sorry.

No worries. For what it's worth, I've retracted my close vote now that this has been edited to ask for official information.

@F1Krazy – Ok… Thx. I'll make sure to make clearer posts in the future.
